# Scoping classes created in Lua using Luabind

Tags: lua, luabind

I am aware that Lua classes can be created using the OO system that Luabind exposes to Lua:

http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind/docs.html#defining-classes-in-lua

```
class 'lua_testclass'

function lua_testclass:__init(name)
    self.name = name
end

function lua_testclass:print()
    print(self.name)
end

a = lua_testclass('example')
a:print()
```

However I am unable to figure out how to scope the class within another namespace so I can do the following:

```
a = MyScope.lua_testclass('example')
a:print()
```

Anyone has a idea. I do not want my classes to pollute the global namespace in Lua.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luabind's `class` function will always pollute the global table. However, you can clean up after it:

```
function newclass(name)
    oldglobal = _G[name]
    class(name)
    cls = _G[name]
    _G[name] = oldglobal
    return cls
end
```

Then you would use it like this:

```
MyScope.lua_testclass = newclass 'lua_testclass'
```

Analogous to `local mod = require 'mod'` you have to spell the name of the class twice, but you could easily build another function on top of this that could be used like `setclass(MyScope, 'lua_testclass')`, automatically putting the class into `MyScope`:

```
function setclass(scope, name) scope[name] = newclass(name) end
```

Disclaimer: All this code is entirely untested.

Answer (score 0):

I did mine a little differently, but it's generally the same concept. Mine doesn't create the class, but rather just moves it. I also implemented it on the C++ side.

To implement what I did in Lua, you would write:

```
function moveClass(name)
    oldGlobal = _G[name]
    _G[name] = nil
    return oldGlobal
end
```

To implement it in C++, you would write:

```
luabind::module(lua) [
    luabind::def("moveClass", +[](lua_State * lua, std::string name) {
        // In the case the class does not exist, this will just 
        // remove nil and return nil. That essentially does nothing.
        luabind::object oldGlobal = luabind::globals(lua)[name];
        luabind::globals(lua)[name] = luabind::nil;
        return oldGlobal;
    })
];
```

So now if you were to use that to move a class you created, you would do this:

```
class 'MyClass'

myTable = {}

myTable.MyClass = moveClass 'MyClass'
```

As an extra note, if you want the moveClass function to give an error in the case that the class you are trying to move does not exist, use luabind::type(oldGlobal) == LUA_TNIL to determine if the class existed or not.

Example:

```
luabind::module(lua) [
    luabind::def("moveClass", +[](lua_State * lua, std::string name) {
        luabind::object oldGlobal = luabind::globals(lua)[name];

        if (luabind::type(oldGlobal) == LUA_TNIL) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Class does not exist.");
        }

        luabind::globals(lua)[name] = luabind::nil;
        return oldGlobal;
    })
];
```